# Can I detect text input change (in form) without POST action in Django?

Tags: python, django, forms

I have Model form with charfield of username.
I want to get value of field after user stopped entering text to use it in my python code in view.

How can I achieve that with Javascript? Is it possible to do it without JS?

Comment: Could you post an example of code, so that your question is clearer / more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jquery + ajax call

```
$('#username').on('input',function(e){
    var input = $(this);
    var username = input.val();
    console.log(username);
    $.post('/some/url/from/your/app/', function(data){
        console.log('sent username to backend');
    })
});
```

You capture `input` event on your `username` input field and send that value to your backend.